# how to compare huge table of mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a huge table of `mysql`which contains more than **33 million records** .How I could compare my `table` to found *non duplicate records* , but unfortunately `select statement` doesn't work. Because it's huge table.

Please provide me a solution

Comment: Can you show what select statement you entered and explain in detail why it doesn't work? Do you get an error message? or what?

Comment: SELECT * from contracts where contracts.subscriber
 not in (SELECT contracts.subscriber from contracts,edms where edms.subscriber=contracts.subscriber)  it's a query but I don't get result it need a huge time to execute

Comment: What are you trying to do with this select ? I can't seem to understand your need.

Comment: create index on relational columns (subscriber)

Answer (score 0):

First, Create a snapshot of your database or the tables you want to compare.

Optionally you can also limit the range of data you want to compare , for example only 3 years of data. This way your select query won't hog all the resources.

Snapshot will be bunch of files each representing a table containg  your primary key or business key for each record  ( I am assuming you can compare data based on aforementioned key . If thats not the case record all the field in your file)

Next, read each records from the file and do a select against the corresponding table. If there are more than 1 record you know it is a duplicate

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at the explain plan and see if what the DB is actually doing for the NOT IN.

You could try refactoring, with an index on subscriber as Roy suggested if necessary. I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to know whether the optimizer will execute these identically.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM contracts 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM edms
          WHERE edms.subscriber=contracts.subscriber
       );

-- or

SELECT C.* 
  FROM contracts AS C
  LEFT
  JOIN edms AS E
    ON E.subscriber = C.subscriber
 WHERE E.subscriber IS NULL;
```